# Create a second loop in Terraform using a condition

Tags: terraform

I'm a true beginner with Terraform, and here is my problem:

- I need to create multiple objects using the same resource of this type:

```
resource "jamf_smartComputerGroup" "test_smart_1" {
  name = "Test Smart 1"
  criteria {
    priority = 0
    name = "UDID"
    search_type = "is"
    search_value = "FAKE-UDID-THAT-ALSO-DOES-NOT-EXIST"
  }
  criteria {
    priority = 1
    name = "UDID"
    search_type = "is not"
    search_value = "FAKE-UDID-THAT-DOES-NOT-EXIST-LIKE-REALLY"
  }
}
```

- IMPORTANT: this resource can have zero or more criterias!
- I have created the `variables.tf` and `terraform.vartf` files as follow:

**`variables.tf`**

```
variable "jamf_smartComputerGroup_list" {
  type = list(object({
    SMCG_NAME = string
    SMCG_CRITERIA = list(object({
      SMCG_CRITERIA_PRIORITY  = number
      SMCG_CRITERIA_NAME      = string
      SMCG_CRITERIA_TYPE      = string
      SMCG_CRITERIA_VALUE     = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

**`terraform.vartf`**

```
jamf_smartComputerGroup_list = [
  {
    SMCG_NAME     = "smcg_1"
    SMCG_CRITERIA = []                      # THIS OBJECT HAS ZERO CRITERIA
  },
  {
    SMCG_NAME = "smcg_2"
    SMCG_CRITERIA = [                       # THIS OBJECT HAS ONE CRITERIA
      {
        SMCG_CRITERIA_PRIORITY  = 0
        SMCG_CRITERIA_NAME      = "crit"
        SMCG_CRITERIA_TYPE      = "is not"
        SMCG_CRITERIA_VALUE     = "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    SMCG_NAME = "smcg_3"
    SMCG_CRITERIA = [                       # THIS OBJECT HAS TWO CRITERIAS
      {
        SMCG_CRITERIA_PRIORITY  = 0
        SMCG_CRITERIA_NAME      = "crit 1"
        SMCG_CRITERIA_TYPE      = "contains"
        SMCG_CRITERIA_VALUE     = "foo"
      },
      {
        SMCG_CRITERIA_PRIORITY  = 1
        SMCG_CRITERIA_NAME      = "crit 2"
        SMCG_CRITERIA_TYPE      = "exact match"
        SMCG_CRITERIA_VALUE     = "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the **`main.tf`** file I was able to loop through the objects, without criterias, using this:

```
resource "jamf_smartComputerGroup" "default" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in var.jamf_smartComputerGroup_list : idx => val }
  name     = each.value.SMCG_NAME
}
```

But and I can't find the appropriate way to determine if one or more criterias are present; and if there is one more criterias, how to loop through them.
A far as I understand, I can't use two `for_each` verbs at the same time, and I can't use `count` with `for_each`.

Any examples will be appreciated :-) !

Regards,
Emmanuel Canault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [dynamic blocks](https://www.cloudbolt.io/terraform-best-practices/terraform-dynamic-blocks/):

```
resource "jamf_smartComputerGroup" "test_smart_1" {

  for_each =  { for idx, val in var.jamf_smartComputerGroup_list : idx => val }

  name = each.value.SMCG_NAME

  dynamic "criteria" {
`   for_each = each.value.SMCG_CRITERIA
    content {
      priority = criteria.SMCG_CRITERIA_PRIORITY
      name = criteria.SMCG_CRITERIA_NAME
      search_type = criteria.SMCG_CRITERIA_TYPE
      search_value =  criteria.SMCG_CRITERIA_VALUE
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Marcin!

It works with small adaptation : `criteria.value.SMCG_...` instead of `criteria.SMCG_...`

Regards,
Emmanuel

Comment: Hey @emmanuel-canault, as this isn't really an answer to your own question, consider writing a comment below Marcin's answer. This keeps the answer section clean and Marcin can update his answer accordingly. Hope you enjoy your journey on the platform, tho!

Comment: Should be a comment, and isn't an answer